# I keep getting the error firebase.database is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, contact-form

I'm trying to link my contact form in a portfolio website to firebase and keep getting (firebase.database is not a function) in my console

This is for the web, using pure javascript

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCzX3r8CFw84WSBuCSXR1fWM_hDrwtGMSs",
  authDomain: "portfolio-4c243.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://portfolio-4c243.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "portfolio-4c243",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "745737502175",
  appId: "1:745737502175:web:a26e5b0baa3769c9"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('messages');


document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

function submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var name = getInputVal('name');
  var email = getInputVal('email');
  var message = getInputVal('message');

  saveMessage(name, email, message);


}

// Function get value
function getInputVal(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

//Save
function saveMessage(name, email, message) {
  var newMessageRef = messagesRef.push();
  newMessageRef.set({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    message: message
  })
}
```

Comment: How do you are importing firebase in your app? With module bundler or from URL ? Show us how you did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is very common and arises because either you have not configured your `config` object correctly or the script tag required for using that particular functionality is missing. 
In your case the `config` object looks fine so you have to add this script in your page

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

But please note that this script is to be added only after the core script for firebase app

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

and for future if you want to use any other service from *Firebase* like *Firestore* or so, just make sure you have that particular script tag in there (with the `config` object correctly setted up).